# How to make chained observable fault tolerant?

Tags: observable, system.reactive, chaining

I have a  event on which i wrap an `Observable.FromEventPattern` around it.I use `Retry` and `Repeat` on this one to make a continous loop.

My problem is the next component which is a `Obserable.Select`.It seems this observable after 2 `throw`-s will just not receive anymore elements for some reason and **ALSO**  stop the upstream  observable (`FromEventPattern`) producing stuff.

I have tried splitting them and now the upstream loop produces messages but the `Select` stops on failed messages.

**Grouped**
`var endless=Observable.FromEventPattern(...).Retry().Repeat().Select(..);` If `Select` fails multiple times, upstream wont produce anymore`
**Segregated**

```
 var loop=Observable.FromEventPattern().Retry().Repeat();
 var map=loop.Select(); //should i add Retry().Repeat()  or try-catch ?
```

How can i chain them and make the `Select` fault tolerant ? Should i just place a `Try-Catch` inside it or also make it with `Retry` ?

Comment: Error and Completion notifications propagate through, so generally you place `Retry` or `Repeat` toward the end of the pipeline (i.e, after `Select`).

Comment: It seems like you're doing something weird here. `FromEventPattern` can produce zero or more elements and it doesn't naturally end so there is no need for a `Repeat()` operator. Also it doesn't throw so there's no need for `Retry()`. You only need to repeat when your observable naturally ends (i.e. something like `Observable.Start` or `Observable.FromAsync`) and you only need to retry when it can produce an error. Can you please post a [mcve]?